# Why is there a continous increase in cycle time when using GEKKO with linux APM solving server?

Tags: python, gekko

I am using GEKKO to study the effect of MPC and MHE on building energy use. To get a performance increase i now switched to a dedicated solving server by setting  `m.GEKKO(remote=True, server='http://10.0.0.10')`. This server is a freshly installed Ubuntu 20.04.1 machine hosting just the linux APmonitor server. Everything works fine so far except that my control and also estimation cycle times increase linearly with every additional solve for the remote solving option. I use my building model with `IMODE=6` for MPC and `IMODE=5` for MHE and both show the same behaviour.

In the following figure you can see the cycle times and solve times for local and remote solve. These tests were conducted with the IPOPT MA57 Solver, but others show the same behavior. My program does not change except for switching from `remote=False` to my solving server `remote=True, server='http://10.0.0.10'`.

[image: Figure of increased cycle time while solving time stays constantly low]

In addition, I have added the timing diagnosis output of the solver after a few steps (left) and after a few hundred steps (right). It clearly shows a much higher system time but very similar solving time but I could not find the culprit here either. Except for this test I have always set `DIAGLEVEL=0` and `m.solve(disp=False)` to reduce the console output.

[image: Timing diagnosis output]

However, re-initializing the GEKKO model and starting again immediately drops the cycle times. This shows that it is not a problem with the server’s compute capacity reducing over time.  For me this looks like some file the process reads and/or writes bloats with the number of iterations but I could not find anything significant in the current model directory. Maybe someone knows the problem and can help me with this one.

**Edit 1:**

Trying the example script provided by John Hedengren in his answer showed a different result for me. The following picture again shows the same linearly increasing behavior. I ran this test with a different physical machine, also using a different physical network adapter at the solving server. Previously i even switched the physical machine of the solving server. Tested with Python Versions 2.7.16, 3.7.7 and 3.8.5.

[image: Example script output]

For me this leads to the conclusion that this situation is not caused by my MPC application. It also doesn't seem to be related to a hardware problem at the client, the network , or the server. IMHO it looks like a server software problem.

A few specs here:

- Ubuntu 20.04.1
- Apache 2.4.41
- PHP 7.4.3
- APMonitor, Version 0.9.2

**Edit 2:**

After using John Hedengrens sample problem to test multiple solving servers i came to the conclusion that the behavior of rising cycle times is not unique to my Ubuntu linux setup. Here a few examples:

- Custom APMonitor server on CentOS7 with MA97Solver (LAN)
  [image: Custom APM on CentOS7]
- APMonitor server on Windows 10 (LAN)
  [image: Standard APM on Windows 10]
- Official APMonitor solving server (Web)
  [image: Official APMonitor solving server]

  to make it make it more obvious i removed the oulierers in the next
  picture [image: Official APMonitor solving server (outliers removed)]

In my case a cycle time increase of about 1 second per 1000 cycles (for this sample problem) happens regardless of the used remote solver (local solve is always fine). The effect of this steady cycle time increase is not as prominent if the solve/cycle times are longer anyway or the number of cycles is not high enough. For my application however this is very problematic as i  have to run about 40k cycles as fast as possible.

**Edit 3:**

Implementing the changes to `gekko.py` and `apm_line.php` John Hedengren suggested in his answer fixed the problem partly but not entirely. There is still an increase in cycle time. Once again, looking closer and longer reveals the issue. The following image shows the output of the usual test script, this time for the updated versions of `gekko.py` and `apm_line.php` a linux APM server (Windows shows same behavior) and 5k steps. Looking very closely you can even see this effect in the diagram (1k runs) John posted in his answer edit.

[image: Rising cycle times for updated gekko]

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example script that solves for 100 cycles with remote (public server) or local solve. The remote (public server) solve is on a Linux server with solver IPOPT. The local solve is on Windows 10 using `apm.exe`. Both are solved with Python 3.7.

[image: Clock and Solve Time]

```py
import numpy as np
from gekko import GEKKO
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time

for ri,r in enumerate([True,False]):
    m = GEKKO(remote=r)
    m.time = np.linspace(0,10,21)
    mass = 500; b = m.Param(value=50); K = m.Param(value=0.8)
    p = m.MV(value=0, lb=0, ub=100); v = m.CV(value=0)
    m.Equation(mass*v.dt() == -v*b + K*b*p)
    m.options.IMODE = 6 #control
    p.STATUS = 1; p.DCOST = 0.1; p.DMAX = 20
    v.STATUS = 1; m.options.CV_TYPE = 2
    v.SP = 40; v.TR_INIT = 1; v.TAU = 5

    s=time.time(); ct=[]; st=[] # cycle time, solve time
    for i in range(100):
        m.solve(disp=False)
        e=time.time(); ct.append(e-s); s=e
        st.append(m.options.SOLVETIME)

    plt.subplot(2,1,1+ri)
    plt.plot(ct,label='clock time')
    plt.plot(st,label='solve time')
    plt.legend()
    if r:
        plt.title('Remote Solve')
    else:
        plt.title('Local Solve')
        plt.xlabel('cycle');
    plt.ylabel('time (sec)')
plt.show()
```

There is no linear increase in solve time with this example. There may be something else happening in the solve loop of your application that is giving a linear increase in time for `remote=True`. It may also be something with the network.

**Information from gekko.py**

The gekko library has different methods for solving remotely versus locally. When solving remotely, the files are created and sent to the server. Results are then generated and passed back to the local temporary directory `m.path` or `m._path` that can be viewed with `m.open_folder()`. One thing to try is to time the steps in the `gekko.py` file. Another thing to observe is the size of the files that are passed to the server.

```py
def send_if_exists(extension):
    path = os.path.join(self._path,self._model_name + '.' + extension)
    if os.path.isfile(path):
        with open(path) as f:
            file = f.read()
        cmd(self._server, self._model_name, extension+' '+file)

#clear apm and csv files already on the server
cmd(self._server,self._model_name,'clear apm')
cmd(self._server,self._model_name,'clear csv')

#send model file
with open(os.path.join(self._path,self._model_name + '.apm')) as f:
    model = f.read()
cmd(self._server, self._model_name, ' '+model)
#send csv file
send_if_exists('csv')
#send info file
send_if_exists('info')
#send dbs file
with open(os.path.join(self._path,'measurements.dbs')) as f:
    dbs = f.read()
cmd(self._server, self._model_name, 'option '+dbs)
#solver options
if self.solver_options:
    opt_file=self._write_solver_options()
    cmd(self._server,self._model_name, ' '+opt_file)

#extra files (eg solver.opt, cspline.data)
for f_name in self._extra_files:
    with open(os.path.join(self._path,f_name)) as f:
        extra_file_data = f.read() #read data
        extra_file_data = 'File ' + f_name + '\n' + extra_file_data + 'End File \n'
    cmd(self._server,self._model_name, ' '+extra_file_data)

#solve remotely
response = cmd(self._server, self._model_name, 'solve', disp, debug)

#print APM error message and die
if (debug >= 1) and ('@error' in response):
    raise Exception(response)

#load results
def byte2str(byte):
    if type(byte) is bytes:
        return byte.decode().replace('\r','')
    else:
        return byte

try:
    results = byte2str(get_file(self._server,self._model_name,'results.json'))
    f = open(os.path.join(self._path,'results.json'), 'w')
    f.write(str(results))
    f.close()
    options = byte2str(get_file(self._server,self._model_name,'options.json'))
    f = open(os.path.join(self._path,'options.json'), 'w')
    f.write(str(options))
    f.close()
    if self.options.CSV_WRITE >= 1:
        results = byte2str(get_file(self._server,self._model_name,'results.csv'))
        with open(os.path.join(self._path,'results.csv'), 'w') as f:
            f.write(str(results))
        if self.options.CSV_WRITE >1:
            results_all = byte2str(get_file(self._server,self._model_name,'results_all.csv'))
            with open(os.path.join(self._path,'results_all.csv'), 'w') as f:
                f.write(str(results_all))
except:
    raise ImportError('No solution or server unreachable.\n'+\
                      '  Show errors with m.solve(disp=True).\n'+\
                      '  Try local solve with m=GEKKO(remote=False).')
```

If a variable such as `response` is growing in size then some of the string operations may be taking longer.

**Edit:** Tried the script with 1000 cycles and there is an increase in cycle time for the remote server.

[image: 1000 cycles]

I checked the server directory and the problem is with the file `overrides.dbs` that grows each cycle when using `remote=True`.

```
-rw-r--r--. 1 apache apache  76911 Jan 26 07:43 overrides.dbs
-rw-r--r--. 1 apache apache 119305 Jan 26 07:43 overrides.dbs
-rw-r--r--. 1 apache apache 219745 Jan 26 07:44 overrides.dbs
```

As this file grows, it takes longer to interpret the longer list of options. To resolve this problem, I made changes to Gekko `gekko.py` and to the server file `apm_line.php`.

Changes to `gekko.py` to appear in Gekko next release beyond 0.2.8) or in [GitHub](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/BYU-PRISM/GEKKO/master/gekko/gekko.py):

```py
            cmd(self._server,self._model_name,'clear meas')
```

```py
            cmd(self._server, self._model_name, 'meas '+dbs)
```

Changes to `apm_line.php` also found on [GitHub](https://github.com/APMonitor/apm_server/blob/master/apm_windows/online/apm_line.php).

```php
        } elseif (strtolower(substr($add, 0, 5))=="meas ") {
                $option = trim(substr($add,5)); // starting at 5th position - extract option
                $fn_opt = $d . "/measurements.dbs";
                if ( !file_exists($fn_opt)) {
                    $meas = fopen ($fn_opt, 'w');
                } else {
                    $meas = fopen ($fn_opt, 'a');
                }
                fwrite ($meas, "\n".$option);
                fclose($meas);
                echo "Successfully added meas: " . $meas;
                fclose($handle);
```

```php
        } elseif  (strtolower($add)=="clear meas") {
                // clear file contents by opening in write mode
                $fn_csv = $d . "/measurements.dbs";
                $meas_file = fopen ($fn_csv, 'w');
                // write a space to the file to clear contents
                fwrite ($meas_file, " ");
                fclose ($meas_file);

                //$clear = "! Cleared measurements.dbs file contents";
                //fwrite ($handle, "\n".$clear);
                fclose($handle);
                echo "Cleared measurements.dbs file";
```

This gives the improved results with no increase in time.

[image: Improved results]

Thanks for your help in finding this bug!

Comment: Thank you, and sorry for my slow response. I tried your script on my setup and found a different result. See my question edit for more information.

Comment: I used Apache server on Windows. The only difference appears to be with the Linux server. The publicly available Linux server is set up with this proceedure: https://apmonitor.com/wiki/index.php/Main/APMonitorServerLinux

Comment: I used the exact same procedure to set up my linux server and additionally i implemented your custom version of the apm file and the libraries (to get the MA97 solver). By using a windows server i can not use these libraries. Probably the situation is caused by some software incompability. Maybe you could provide me with some software version details (Linux, Apache, PHP) of the linux server machine so i can run a test with the same versions here.

Comment: I use CentOS 7 and keep Apache and PHP updated to the latest versions with the `yum` package manager.

Comment: Thank you for this information. I added a second edit to my question where i show the results of using CentOS and also other servers. I find the time delay to happen with any remote server. Maybe you can try to run your example script for more than 100 cycles to see the effect.

Comment: This is excellent analysis. I'll try running it for more than 100 cycles. I wonder if a profiler would help find the source of the time increase: https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html#module-cProfile

Comment: Thanks for your help - bug is fixed and fix is available now on GitHub or for the next release of Gekko (beyond 0.2.8).

Comment: Thank you John for the first step of fixing this problem. Changing/adding the code lines solved a large part of the problem. However the `apm_line.php` file you linked from GitHub does also have other changes compared to the previous versions. The canges in the lines 49-50 cause a file not found error for Windows and Linux server if i directly use the new files. Manually changing just the code sections in the old files works. Also the original problem is not entirely fixed. See my new Edit 3.

Comment: Thanks - I updated the Windows executable name to apm.exe in the apm_line.php file. `$solve = 'apm.exe ' . $d;`. Do you see any files growing in size in the online run directory of your server?

Comment: I now compared the file sizes in the online directory. Running the example script 500 times and running it 5000 times results in the exact same file sizes. However the cycle times quadruple.

Comment: Thanks for checking that - it may be in one of the variables that is stored locally in memory.

Comment: Can you give an example case that shows this increase?

Comment: Please see Edit3 in my question. The last picture shows exactly this situation.

Comment: Got it. I'll run for more than 1000 cycles (up to 5000) to see the increase.